# Cannot Execute a EXE file If Tomcat Running as a service in java

Tags: java, tomcat, exe

I am using **Apache tomcat (7.0.39)** to run my java web application . 
 In that application I am calling the executable file . It is working well if I start the Tomcat using 
 `Startup.bat` . If I start Tomcat as a service , Executable file doesn't run and windows shows

```
"Exe file encoutered a problem . We are sorry for the inconvenience caused"
```

I need this because tomcat starts during Windows startup. If I start the Tomcat using `Startup.bat` , then the command prompt opens and it doesn't exit. It remains open . Anyone give solution ?

Comment: Are you using relative path of that exe?, if yes, check the path..

Comment: No, I use absolute path it is working well if i run tomcat using startup.bat . If run as service it doesn't execute a exe file .

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will run as a different user when started as a service, check if that user has permission to execute the exe file.

Or maybe the exe accesses other files via a relative path and only finds them when started via command line.

Comment: I Login as a Administrator , it should have the permission to execute a exe file . How can i start tomcat using Starup.bat with command prompt hidden or closed ?

Comment: As I said, when started as a service, tomcat will run as "Local Service" or something like that by default. You can change that though, just go to the properties of the service (My Computer->Manage->... Services and the right click). There you should see a tab where you can set the user it starts as.

As for running tomcat without command window, I'm not sure but maybe try using "javaw.exe" instead of "java.exe". I think the bat-file itself will keep the window open though.